# Audio playback: part of song is skipped

Tags: sound, 12.10, vlc, totem, clementine

I am experiencing some problems with music playback after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10.
Basically some of the songs stop playing after some time as if the song has ended. It's always the same songs and the same time. The weird thing that it happens with Clementine and Totem but VLC doesn't have this problem and it also plays as it should on Windows. I'm guessing there might be a problem with some library that's shared with by the first two applications. I don't know if it's relevant but the file format of the audio files is flac(don't know if the problem affects mp3, because I don't have many of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found the reason behind this issue but at least I have found a workaround.

I just decoded the file using flac -d and encoded it again with flac -e and it plays as it should.

As I have said before I'm not sure if this affects mp3's, obviously if it does this workaround wont work since mp3 is a lossy format.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, it seems to be a GStreamer problem, VLC doesn't have an issue since it doesn't use GStreamer, whereas Totem and Clementine do. I've found the command-line program gst-play-1.0 also does this. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7656541/) is the output for a song that has this issue. I have reported this as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-base1.0/+bug/1330816).